# Where should BrowserRouter go?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have a working React/Redux Router app, implemented with `react-router-dom 4.2.2` and `react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.9`.

I'd like to add the basename `/calendar` to all paths though, via [BrowserRouter's basename API](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) that looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

But this far I haven't had any use for `BrowserRouter`, so I don't knwo really where it should go.

I have tried to encapsulate (+ put it next to as in the example above) the `NavLink`s  as well as the `Route`s with `BrowserRouter`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

As my app works fine without `BrowserRouter` - is it an optional part of `react-router` or is it already integrated somehow in `react-router-redux`?

**Update**

This is how I've tried to encapsulate `NavLink` and/or `Route` with `BrowserRouter`:

```
const ComponentA = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter basename='/calendar'>
      <NavLink exact to="/a">Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
)

const ComponentB = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter basename='/calendar'>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Could you, please, show the part of your app, where you are using the `Router` component?

Comment: I've updated the question with one thing I've tried. But just to be clear, before needing `basename` I haven't used `BrowserRouter` as everything has worked perfectly without it.

Comment: BrowserRouter is usually used in your topmost Parent component. Check this post on medium: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: Oh yes, that works!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <BrowserRouter basename='/calendar'>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```